# Check and uncheck in different td tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, input, html-table

I expose my problem.

I have different input type checkboxes in different td's. When I check a checkbox, I want the others unchecked.

My JavaScript function works, but only when it is in the same td although each input is in the same class...

I added a fiddle to make you see it:

[`1`](https://jsfiddle.net/vhho1Le4/#&togetherjs=JigV8zEJrE)

Do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$('input[type="checkbox"]').not(this)` to exclude current check-box. [`.siblings`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) will only select *siblings of each element in the set of matched elements*

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function() {
    $('input[type="checkbox"].CheckAccre').not(this).prop('checked', false);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Check-box without class:
<input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="Bloc11" value="O" />
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="Bloc11" value="O" class="CheckAccre" />
      <label for="<%# Bloc11.ClientID %>" class="pure-checkbox" id="Bloc1L" runat="server" style="margin: 0px;">
        Demandeur d'emploi indemnisé/indemnisable</label>
      <br />
      <input type="checkbox" value="N" runat="server" id="Bloc12" class="CheckAccre" />
      <label for="<%# Bloc12.ClientID %>" class="pure-checkbox" id="Bloc12L" runat="server" style="margin: 0px;">
        Demandeur d'emploi non indemnisé inscrit à l'ANPE six mois au cours des huit derniers mois</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Bénéficiaire du
      <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="RSA" value="1" class="CheckAccre" />
      <label for="<%# RSA.ClientID %>" class="pure-checkbox" id="RSAL" runat="server" style="margin: 0px;">RSA</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" runat="server" id="RMI" class="CheckAccre" />
      <label for="<%# RMI.ClientID %>" class="pure-checkbox" id="RMIL" runat="server" style="margin: 0px;">RMI</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" runat="server" id="ASS" class="CheckAccre" />
      <label for="<%# ASS.ClientID %>" class="pure-checkbox" id="ASSL" runat="server" style="margin: 0px;">ASS</label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="4" runat="server" id="ATA" class="CheckAccre" />
      <label for="<%# ATA.ClientID %>" class="pure-checkbox" id="ATAL" runat="server" style="margin: 0px;">ATA</label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/vhho1Le4/1/)

**Edit:** To achieve the same using **`jQuery.fn.extend()`**, Use `this` in the handler as `this` will be nothing but `jQuery-object` on which `extended-instance` is called.

```js
jQuery.fn.extend({
  CheckDecheck: function() {
    var _this = this;
    _this.on('change', function() {
      _this.not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });
  }
});

$(function() {
  $('.OUINONA534').CheckDecheck();
  $('.TESTTEST').CheckDecheck();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      test 1
      <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="Bloc11" value="O" class="OUINONA534" />
      <br />test 2
      <input type="checkbox" value="N" runat="server" id="Bloc12" class="OUINONA534" />
    </td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan='2'>
      <hr>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      test 3
      <input type="checkbox" runat="server" id="Checkbox1" value="O" class="TESTTEST" />
      <br />test 4
      <input type="checkbox" value="N" runat="server" id="g" class="TESTTEST" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Oh ! Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: I'm glad it helped! _Happy Coding_

Comment: Another question, I have other checkbox without class . However, he let fly when I click on a checkbox with a class , how to change javascript function so that it delivers the input of the same class ?

Comment: Ok , thanks! In your edit , you wrote the class but may be a single function for different class ? For I checkbox different group with different class

Comment: Yes! You must have different handlers for different selectors!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vjnok5av/#&togetherjs=JigV8zEJrE     
I want to like this, it is possible?